# When setting up a stateful widget, does it matter if we use "const"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I haven't given it much thought up until now, but I've seen example code with and without the `const` in the

```
class ScreenBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenBuilder({ Key? key, required this.tVars, required this.randomHash, this.overrideMe = false, this.gotoSp = 0}) : super(key:key);
  final ThreadVars tVars;
  final String randomHash;
  final bool overrideMe;
  final int gotoSp;

  @override
  _ScreenBuilderState createState() => _ScreenBuilderState();

}
```

Specifically talking about this line:

```
  ScreenBuilder({ Key? key, required this.tVars, required this.randomHash, this.overrideMe = false, this.gotoSp = 0}) : super(key:key);
```

vs

```
  const ScreenBuilder({ Key? key, required this.tVars, required this.randomHash, this.overrideMe = false, this.gotoSp = 0}) : super(key:key);
```

What is the difference if any?  My widget seems to work the same in either permutation

**For bonus points**, I remember reading an article that mentioned if I were to call my `ScreenBuilder(...)` widget like this: `const ScreenBuilder(...)` I would see some performance improvements but putting a const infront of it of course throws a whole bunch of getter errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `const` keyword before your constructor when all your class properties are declared as `final`. Eventually, it will make them immutable in any scenario in future.

For example, if you create an instance of that class you will not be able to change the value of those properties using that instance.

In fact, using `const` before the constructor can contribute to the betterment of performance as it prevents unnecessary rebuild of widget properties. Moreover it saves memory too.

[Try this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-const-keyword-demystified-c8d2a2609a80), very well explained. I am adding an excerpt here below,

> The fact that it saves memory is not the only importance of const widgets. Because an object is marked as constant, flutter knows that in the case of a rebuild, it makes no sense to rebuild that object since “it should not have changed”. This is a great performance boost as once an object is built, in the lifetime of the app, it will remain the same, and that is just spectacular and improves even the hot restart functionality of flutter as it knows where and what to rebuild based on changes.